# My application loads a webview and adds another webview over the view

Tags: ios

why this error occurs:

I have a view over which i added a webview and opened a url on it.At some specific url i want to add another webview over the view and hide my first webview.In that case my webview is not showing any contents.

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

This the the code:

```
-(void)youtube_page
{

   [webview1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47pwcfo9E_s"]]];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Back)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;


     [webview addSubview:webview1];
}
```

Comment: its looks like infinate loop you had create. show some code

Comment: plz check the code i have added

Comment: i think there is no problem with the above code show webview delegate methods

Comment: Why adding `webView1` in `webView` and to in `self.view`? If you set your `webView` to `hidden` or something like this it will hide your newly created `webView1` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your `-(void)youtube_page` method. See last line of code

```
[webview addSubview:webview1];
```

You are adding your second `webView` inside your first `webView` and when you set it to `hidden` you will hide your second `webView` inside it as well.

To fix this problem just add your second `webView` in your `mainView` like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:webView1];
```

Comment: [webview1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47pwcfo9E_s"]]]; this url is not working it shows a blank page and when i remove the youtube Id and pass "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v" then it works.what could be the reason behind it